# Client certificate authentication in Flutter/Dart languege

Tags: dart, certificate, flutter, x509certificate, client-certificates

I am fairly new in certificates world. I decided to create an application that is obligated to use a certificate to access the API.

I created a self-signed CA certificate, SSL Certificate and a client certificate. I imported them into Windows Server and configured IIS properly. I am able to make a request with clientcertificate.pfx file to API from browser (Google Chrome). The pfx certificate is imported to personal user store via MMC. To create pfx file I used  .cert and .pvk files.

So far so good.

Now I am trying to make a request from dart and don't know what files I should send to API.
Should I send the pfx file? Or maybe .cert and .pvk files? 
Have you ever done it guys? Could someone help me a bit with understanding this proccess?
I have already read a lot of websites but still didn't find answers. 
In mobile development world I am totally new too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dart's `HttpClient` can take a `SecurityContext`.

> To add a custom trusted certificate authority, or to *send a client
>   certificate to servers that request one*, pass a SecurityContext object
>   as the optional `context` argument to the HttpClient constructor. The
>   desired security options can be set on the SecurityContext object.

Store your PKCS12 client keystore (the pfx file) somewhere in your app, probably as an asset, and load it on startup. Create a `SecurityContext` and then call both `useCertificateChainBytes` and `usePrivateKeyBytes` passing the same values to both (the pfx file's contents and password).

Use that `SecurityContext` as the `context` of your `HttpClient`.

Comment: working also using .jks file (java key store from java keytool)

Comment: Hey how can give path from assets to securityContext.

Comment: i have traied this 
    var context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
    context.setTrustedCertificates(filepath, password)

Comment: I am doing like this 
    var context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
    context.setTrustedCertificates(filePath ,password) // how can we get file path from assets

Comment: Read the keystore asset into memory see [Adding assets](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images), then use `setTrustedCertificatesBytes(List<int> certBytes, { String password })`

Comment: @RichardHeap for some reason some unspecified error happens when I#m using HttpClient with your specified security context.

Answer (score 1):

You do the client side authenticate by loading the bytes into memory like this final cert = await RootBundle.load('assets/cert.pfx'); . Then create a SecurityContext and then call both useCertificateChainBytes and usePrivateKeyBytes. use the this SecurityContext as your HttpClient context.