# How to deal with certificate files when making API calls from Flutter App?

Tags: ssl, flutter, security-context

I have a Flutter Application that makes HTTP requests to an API I've hosted on my server.
My API is behind a secure connection (with SSL certificate) and i want my App to make HTTPS requests so the connection is secure.
I've read in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52359591/8199897 that i can provide the KEY and Certificate using `SecurityContext`.
My question is:
- Are those certificate and key files we reffere to inside `SecurityContext` the same we got when we created SSL certificate on server?
- And what if the certificate files expired and we had to renew them on server? how to use the new files? should we make an update to the App on the store?

Comment: Is your server certificate self-signed or signed by a CA?

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing as @RichardHeap. If it is signed by a CA then simply do `http.get("https://yourapi.whatever")`. If it isn't well you could fiddle around to get the phone to accept a self signed cert... but IMHO it isn't worth the effort, domain validated cert. is fine and you can get it for like 6$ per year.

Comment: Thanks for answers! And yes it's self signed certificates not signed by CA, I think I'll go forward getting a CS certificates.
Just one more clarification: In case of CA certificates, is it enough to call  http.get("https://yourapi.whatever") without providing certificates in the request?

Comment: If you were to try `http.get("https://yourapi.whatever")` with a self signed cert. then you'd get `HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate(handshake.cc:354))`.With a CA signed cert. it will work straight out of the box (you don't need to mess around with importing certs. into the phone). With a CA signed server cert. communication between the client and server will be encrypted in both ways and you don't need to provide anything from the client end. Client certs. are used to validate the identity of a client, do you need that?

Comment: @Uroš, Thanks a lot! No i don't need to identify the client identity, i do it through Auth. That was helpful.