# Setting up ssl for http: ^0.12.0 package

Tags: http, ssl, flutter, pinning

I wonder how can I setup ssl for http(http: ^0.12.0) package in Flutter, 
without migrating to dart:io.

Currently I'm using:

```
http.Client httpClient = http.Client();
```

and I do not see any options there to setup ssl.

Do I have to use

```
final SecurityContext context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
HttpClient client = HttpClient(context);
```

from dart:io?

Comment: AFAIK, it should Just Work. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm getting
HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
 CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:352))

In order to migrate to dart:io, I would have to refactor some portion of code, and I would avoid that if I can :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do SSL pinning via self generated signed certificates in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323603/how-to-do-ssl-pinning-via-self-generated-signed-certificates-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HttpOverride to make the Client ignore bad certificates as mentioned on this [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/458#issuecomment-932652512). This is only recommended to be used in development builds.

```dart
class DevHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
        ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

Then initialize the HttpOverride to be used.

```dart
HttpOverrides.global = DevHttpOverrides();
```