# How to pin public key of SSL certificate in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, ssl, https

Could someone help me on implementing SSL public key pinning in flutter? I have searched a lot in google but I did not find a proper article that explains how this can be implemented.

Kindly help !!!

Comment: https://learnpainless.com/flutter/how-implement-ssl-pinning-your-flutter-app/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192261/how-to-do-ssl-public-key-pinning-in-flutter-dart

Comment: I have already checked these

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called `http_certificate_pinning` which provides 3 different APIs to use. You can check it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/http_certificate_pinning).

1-As an interceptor for Dio:

```
import 'package:http_certificate_pinning/certificate_pinning_interceptor.dart';
  
  // Add CertificatePinningInterceptor in dio Client
  Dio getClient(String baseUrl, List<String> allowedSHAFingerprints){
      var dio =  Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: baseUrl))
        ..interceptors.add(CertificatePinningInterceptor(allowedSHAFingerprints));
      return dio;
  }

  myRepositoryMethod(){ 
    dio.get("myurl.com");
  }
```

2-Creating an http client:

```
import 'package:http_certificate_pinning/secure_http_client.dart';
  
  // Uses SecureHttpClient to make requests
  SecureHttpClient getClient(List<String> allowedSHAFingerprints){
      final secureClient = SecureHttpClient.build(certificateSHA256Fingerprints);
      return secureClient;
  }

  myRepositoryMethod(){ 
    secureClient.get("myurl.com");
  }
```

3-Checking if the handshake happens correctly and do whatever you want:

```
import 'package:http_certificate_pinning/http_certificate_pinning.dart';
  
Future myCustomImplementation(String url, Map<String,String> headers, List<String> allowedSHAFingerprints) async {
  try{
    final secure = await HttpCertificatePinning.check(
      serverURL: url,
      headerHttp: headers,
      sha: SHA.SHA256,
      allowedSHAFingerprints:allowedSHAFingerprints,
      timeout : 50
    );

    if(secure.contains("CONNECTION_SECURE")){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }catch(e){
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, do you know how can I get allowedSHAFingerprints?

Comment: Check this: https://pub.dev/packages/http_certificate_pinning#get-certificate-fingerprint @AhmedAdel

Answer (score 1):

You can use `certificate_pinning_httpclient: ^0.0.3` it allow us to use public key pinning and you can also add backup key init

```
static const String publicKey =
      "Xs+pjRp23QkmXeH31KEAjM1aWvxpHT6vYy+q2ltqtaM="; // Add your own public key
static const String backupKey =
      "Xs+pjRp23QkmXeH31KEAjM1aWvxpHT6vYy+q2ltqtaM="; // you can also add backup key

 import 'package:certificate_pinning_httpclient/certificate_pinning_httpclient.dart';

// with http
final client = IOClient(CertificatePinningHttpClient(
        [publicKey,backupKey]));

// with Dio
final _dio = Dio();
(_dio.httpClientAdapter as IOHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
    (client) => CertificatePinningHttpClient(
        ["S4kZuhQQ1DPcMOCYFQXD0gG+UW0zmyVx6roNWpRl65I="]);
```