How to implement SSL Pinning in Flutter
I want to implement the SSL Pinning (specifically public key pinning) in Flutter without using any flutter or dart plugin.
What can be the possible way?

Is there any Internal Dart methods?
Is there any custom native code callable from method channel?


Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323603/how-to-do-ssl-pinning-via-self-generated-signed-certificates-in-flutter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726406/how-can-i-do-public-key-pinning-in-flutter/54838348#54838348 ?
