# don´t add certificate in Flutter

Tags: html, http, flutter, certificate, httpresponse

I want to get a http-response in Flutter. I already have a working code, but there I need to put the certificate in a direction.

Is there an option, that I don´t need to add the certificate? I want to develop an flexible app which works also if the certificate of the Website changes. From the website I only need the html-code, nothing else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do SSL pinning via self generated signed certificates in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323603/how-to-do-ssl-pinning-via-self-generated-signed-certificates-in-flutter)

Comment: The linked question shows you how to validate the server's certificate yourself, programatically. Make the validation method as simple (simply return true!) or as complex (check the CN, validity, signature, etc) as you like.